# React Datepicker Show Previous Year in Popover

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I'm using https://reactdatepicker.com/

Right now the default start date is the current date. I want the start date to be Start year of 1970. I dont want to disable the previous dates, just want the calendar to display the Date as 1st January 1970, so that the user can select the date of birth.

This is my current code:

```
class ReactDatePicker extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      startDate: new Date() - 80
    }
    this.datepickerRef = React.createRef();
  }

  setDate = date => {
    this.props.onChange(this.props.name, date);
  };

  handleClickDatepickerIcon = () => {
    const datepickerElement = this.datepickerRef;
    datepickerElement.setFocus(true);
  }

  render() {
    const { name, value } = this.props;

    return (
      <Datepicker 
        id={name}
        name={name}
        selected={value}
        onChange={this.setDate}
        startDate={this.state.startDate}
        maxDate={new Date()}
        popperPlacement="bottom"
        dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy"
        showMonthDropdown="true"
        showYearDropdown="true"
        placeholderText="Select a date"
        ref={el => this.datepickerRef = el}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If you wanted a date 80 years back you should use 
`date.setFullYear( date.getFullYear() - 80 );`

Comment: @RST This actually removes the placeholder text....

Comment: I was merely indicating your -80 doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @RST By changing the selected prop to the previous year works. But it hides the placeholder text and displays the year there.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the prop which displays the desired year in the popup.
openToDate={new Date("1970/01/1")}
So the final code will be

```
<Datepicker 
        id={name}
        name={name}
        selected={value}
        onChange={this.setDate}
        startDate={this.state.startDate}
        maxDate={new Date()}
        popperPlacement="bottom"
        dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy"
        showMonthDropdown="true"
        showYearDropdown="true"
        placeholderText="Select a date"
        openToDate={new Date("1960/01/1")}
        ref={el => this.datepickerRef = el}
      />
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example from the documentation that set a default date to 1st January 1970.

```
    () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date(null));
  return (
    <DatePicker selected={startDate} onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)} />
  );
};
```

I just added null as a parameter to date, so that is create a date object with the date of 01/01/1970.

In your instance you could just do:

```
this.state = {
      startDate: new Date(null)
    }
```

Comment: This actually removes the placeholder text. It displays the date at start instead of placeholder